# Understanding the effect of c( ) on named vectors

Tags: r, list, vector, concatenation

Why is:

```
c(d = 1:3)
```

equal to a named vector, as:

```
d1 d2 d3 
1  2  3
```

And where is this behavior documented?

The c help file does say:

```
## do *not* use
c(ll, d = 1:3) # which is == c(ll, as.list(c(d = 1:3))
```

but the `as.list` is superfluous (and the closing parenthesis missing). And I don't think that amounts to documentation of the behavior above.

Comment: why ? Just because it's convenient I suppose. It's allowed for vectors to have several elements identically named though: `c(c(a=1),c(a=2))` or 'names<-'(c(1,2),rep("a",2))

Comment: By 556 rep, you'd think you could pay attention to tag definitions when writing a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nice observation which took me to the actual C Code (since `c()` is a Primitive function). Just sharing my observation from the code.

And in the [actual C](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/bind.c) code `do_c()` function that does this `c()` for R and inside that function there's a section dedicated to assign attributes to the output.

```
/* Build and attach the names attribute for the returned object. */

    if (data.ans_nnames && data.ans_length > 0) {
    PROTECT(data.ans_names = allocVector(STRSXP, data.ans_length));
    data.ans_nnames = 0;
    while (args != R_NilValue) {
        struct NameData nameData;
        nameData.seqno = 0;
        nameData.count = 0;
        NewExtractNames(CAR(args), R_NilValue, TAG(args), recurse, &data, &nameData);
        args = CDR(args);
    }
    setAttrib(ans, R_NamesSymbol, data.ans_names);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    }
```

which tells us `NewExtractNames()` is the function that specifically create names and exploring that we can find the information that the sequence is created

```
/* NewExtractNames(v, base, tag, recurse):  For c() and  unlist().
 * On entry, "base" is the naming component we have acquired by
 * recursing down from above.
 *  If we have a list and we are recursing, we append a new tag component
 * to the base tag (either by using the list tags, or their offsets),
 * and then we do the recursion.
 *  If we have a vector, we just create the tags for each element. */
```

So, to your question it doesn't seem to have been documented anywhere that attribute names are generated with a sequence and assigned it to the result.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify this behaviour changing `use.names` parameter:

```
c(d = 1:3)
d1 d2 d3 
 1  2  3 
c(d = 1:3,use.names=F)
[1] 1 2 3
```

More details here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/c